# How do I make an operation from a list with operators and values?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a function that takes in a list that has operators and values and returns the total using the operators given.

ex:

[4, '-', 8, '-', 1] should equal -5

I know that I can use the import operator to change the operator from a string to a working operator but I don't know how to properly use it.

Comment: (not actually recommending this, but for fun `eval("print(" + " ".join(str(x) for x in myList) + ") ")` will do the calculation as long as what is entered makes a valid python expression.)

Comment: You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to avoid the occasionally dangerous behavior of `eval`. `ast.literal_eval(''.join(map(str, l)))`